# Conversão de Oracle para SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, conversão

> **Contexto:** Atualmente trabalho em um sistema que utiliza o banco de dados [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle), porém agora vou precisar que o sistema utilize [sqlserver](/questions/tagged/sqlserver).

Meu objetivo é converter `DDL` e `DML` para [sqlserver](/questions/tagged/sqlserver), vejo que tem algumas diferenças como:

`Number` para `Numeric`
`Varchar2` para `Varchar`
`Data` para `DataTime`

Entretanto queria fazer isso de maneira automática, ou pelo menos
ter as equivalencias de forma mais completa para ajudar nesse processo.

Seria interessante também comendar dificuldade que eu venha a ter
pois também tenho `Triggers`, `Procedures`, `Functions`, etc.

Obrigado

Comment: Acho que o que não existe uma solução direta para o que você quer. Você tem alguma experiência com programação com Java?

Comment: Não, mas se tiver alguma ideia.. mesmo que em Java, já é alguma coisa :)

Comment: Certo. No java existe o JPA tecnologia criada para tornar os programas independeres de banco de dados. Você cria as classes e utiliza annotation e a a partir das classes as tabelas no banco são criadas. Aqui entra minha ideia o JPA também permite que a partir de um banco de dados as classes sejam criadas. Minha ideia é criar as classes a partir do JPA e com essas classes, alterando a conexão, criar as tabelas no SQL Server.

Comment: Na questão de dados acho que o import/export do proprio SQL Server pode consultar no Oracle e carregar no SQL. Caso contrário você pode criar um programa java só pra isso. Agora trigger, procedure e function vai ter que convertida na mão mesmo.

Comment: Interessante @Krismorte obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei uma solução que resolve meu problema, o [SQlines SQL Converter](https://github.com/dmtolpeko/sqlines), faz conversões de vários tipos de bancos:

SQlies SQL Converter é uma ferramenta open source (Apache License 2.0) que permite converter esquema de banco de dados (DDL), consultas e DML, views, stored procedures, packages, functions e triggers entre o Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, IBM DB2, MySQL , PostgreSQL, Sybase, Informix, Teradata, Netezza e Greenplum.

O mesmo ainda tem uma [Conversor Online](http://www.sqlines.com/online), mas também pode ser baixado a [versão trial](http://www.sqlines.com/download). Entretanto, é [pago](http://www.sqlines.com/purchase).

Mesmo assim resolveu meu problema.